# Extract several columns from 3d matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, matrix-indexing

I currently have an array A which has dimensions N x t x t. I want to create a 2D matrix, N x t, of the form:

```
B = [ A[:,1,1] A[:,2,2],...,A[:,t,t]]
```

Obviously, 2 ways I could do this are writing it out in full (impractical since t is large) and loops (potentially slow). Is there a way to do this without loops. I figured it would work if I did:

```
B = A[:,[1:end],[1:end]]
```

but that just gave me back the original matrix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, you need to start thinking about how to reorganize your matrix.

From

```
A = randn([5 3 3]);
```

Let's look at

```
A(:,:)
```

Basically you want columns 1, 5, 9. Thinking about it, knowing t = 3, from the present column you want to increment by t + 1. The formula is basically:

```
((1:3)-1)*(3+1)+1 %(or (0:2)*(3+1) + 1)
```

Which plugged in A yields your solution

```
A(:,((1:3)-1)*(3+1)+1)
```

In a general format, you can do:

```
A(:,((1:t)-1)*(t+1)+1)
```

EDIT:

Amro basically just put me to shame. The idea is still the same, it just becomes more readable thanks to `end`

Therefore use:

```
A(:,1:t+1:end)
```

Comment: +1: yup, definitely the best way to go. Wouldn't win any prizes for readability, but there's comments for that :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Unfortunately readability and math seldom go hand in hand.

Comment: @Rasman: all the credit goes to you :) I'm trying to find a mention of this in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html#f1-86846) but I cant..

Comment: @Amro: Correct me if I'm misreading, but in fact the documentation states for this case: "Two subscripts always access the **first page** of a multidimensional array", implying that the behavior we see here for `(:, [...])` is a bug...?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: weird right? fortunately Octave behaves the same way here, so it must be a feature not a bug

Comment: @Amro: well, a "useful bug" any way :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take on that subject:

```
mask = repmat(logical(permute(eye(size(A,2)), [3 1 2])), size(A,1), 1);
newA = reshape(A(mask), size(A,1), []);
```

Just generate mask, apply it and reshape result to the right shape.

Edit:

Or even simpler:

```
newA = A(:, logical(eye(size(A,2))))
```

or along the same lines,

```
newA = A(:, diag(true(size(A,2),1)));
```

which is a tad faster.

Comment: +1: not bad (although I fear @Rasman cannot be beaten in this case :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I also think so, but with a bit of tinkering my version can get much neater too ;) See my edit.

Comment: +1 that second one is also very interesting, and I'm surprised it even works! Logical indexing usually requires a mask of the same size as the matrix: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1

Comment: @Amro: I have to agree. I've stumbled upon this notation before, used it a few times thought nothing of it (and then forgot all about it). Now that we're talking about it, it actually makes less and less sense...

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB is pretty good with vectors and matrices, but when it comes to "general arrays" you'll often have to switch to "general methods". When you're used to the ease with which you manipulate matrices/vectors, this will seem really clumsy, backward and not very convenient at all (there's actually very defendable reasons for that, but that's a discussion for another time :).

The version below loops through each page via `arrayfun` (which is only faster than a normal loop for large matrices) and calls `diag` on each page:

```
% "flip" the array, so that 3rd dimension becomes the 1st (rows), and 
% the 1st dimension becomes the 3rd, so that each "page" is a regular 
% matrix. You want the diagonals of all these matrices.
b = permute(a, [3 2 1]);

% Now "loop" through the pages, and collect the matrix diagonal for each page
c = arrayfun(@(ii)diag(b(:,:,ii)), 1:size(b,3), 'UniformOutput', false);

% The above will output a cell-array, which you can cast back to 
% a numeric matrix through this operation: 
A = [c{:}];
```

Comment: Quite the contrast from "A(:,1:t+1:end)" ;) What do you mean general arrays though? A cell array? Because you can more or less index into cell arrays just like matrices I believe.

Comment: @Shaun314: no, I meant an array that is not 1- or 2 dimensional (vector or matrix), but `N`-dimensional.

Comment: Ah gotcha, makes a little bit more sense now :)